# Shuffling Cards by Grouping

Tags: probability, statistics, algorithmic-randomness

Lets say I have 5 cards, a b c d and e. I group those as 2, 2 and 1, my first group contains a and b, second group contains c and d, and the last group contains only e. Then I mix those, by putting the last group on top and putting the first group to bottom, so my deck is now sorted as e c d a b, then I continue this procedure till I have a deck that is all random. 
How many steps I should continue this procedure?

 What is the general formula if I have 52 cards and group those as 12 12 14  14?

Comment: It's _never_ all random, since if you specify the number of shuffles, the order of the final result is uniquely determined.

Comment: @quasi so how can it be close to random, since the numbers of groups are not same, order of the deck should change

Comment: You need to randomize the number $n$ of shuffles, subject to some discrete distribution on $n$.

Comment: The question is what is that number n in order for it to be all random

Comment: There is no such number $n$. As I said, $n$ itself needs to be random.

Comment: I take randomness as a term to define the variation distance. So n should be a minimum number to make that variation distance close to 0. When shuffling, n needs to be random but in order to make that deck random as well, n can get a minimum number if we are working on it, otherwise there won't be such a thing like optical numbers to make riffle shuffle.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said.

Comment: I advise you to look at "Proofs from the Book" shuffling decks chapter.

Comment: When riffling, the decision of which card goes above the other is randomised, either automatically or by the inherent lack of precision in timing the release of cards. You are deterministically moving the blocks of cards. Explain why you believe your system can be random when it uses a deterministic system and a determined value for $n$ (hint: it cannot).

Answer (score 1):

For the case of the $5$-card shuffle you described, we get
\begin{align*}
0\;\text{shuffles}\implies\;a, b, c, d, e\\[4pt]
1\;\text{shuffles}\implies\;e, c, d, a, b\\[4pt]
2\;\text{shuffles}\implies\;b, d, a, e, c\\[4pt]
3\;\text{shuffles}\implies\;c, a, e, b, d\\[4pt]
4\;\text{shuffles}\implies\;d, e, b, c, a\\[4pt]
5\;\text{shuffles}\implies\;a, b, c, d, e\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so there are only $5$ distinct results, after which, the sequence repeats.

As to which of those $5$ possible results is the most random, it depends on your definition of "most random", but whatever it is, simply test each of those $5$ results, and take the one that best fits your "most random" criterion.

Comment: What happens if I try that in 52 cards

Comment: First answer which of those $5$ decks is the one you regard as the "most random", and why.

Comment: I regard the 3rd one most random because after that it will getting close to the original deck

Comment: But you need a _definition_ of "most random", otherwise the question is not meaningful.

Comment: Defitinition is according to term "Variation Distance" that probabilists have created in order to measure randomness

Comment: Because the process you describe is symmetric, both the second and third are equally random, according to your definition. Every card in each sequence has a corresponding card in the other in all sensible measures of distortion from the initial order.

Comment: @Demir Ekin: What is your calculated variation distance after $1,2,3,4,5$ shuffles, respectively?